# Clear all textboxes client side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

Can I Simulate this Code With JQUERY or Javascript?

```
    IEnumerable<TextBox> Textboxes = (from c in pnlform.Controlswhere    object.ReferenceEquals(c.GetType(), typeof(TextBox))c).AsEnumerable().Cast<TextBox>();
foreach (TextBox item in Textboxes) {
item.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

i want to clear all textboxes without any roundtrip to server.

Comment: JavaScript is an event-driven language. What circumstances would lead to the elements being cleared? If you want the user to click a button to clear a form, you should use the <input type="reset" /> button. What I'm trying to get at is that you need to provide more details.

Comment: @zzzBov : You Are Right i have to use <input type="reset" /> button. does it work for all controls ? like checkbox radio button and...

Comment: it works for all controls in the same `form` as your cancel button. They all will be reset to their initial value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't really understand that code, but to clear a textbox with jQuery:

```
$('someselector').val('');
```

So to clear all textboxes on a page:

```
$('input[type=text]').val('');
```

Or you could use good old' `form.reset()`

Comment: This Code will Clear all textboxes on a collection of controls. thanks for your code but it will clear just one textbox but i want do it for  all textboxes with Loop is it possible? thanks

Comment: @shaahin - no it won't clear just one textbox, it will clear any textbox that matches the supplied jQuery selector. there is no need to loop. @zzzzBov is right - what are you trying to do? at what point do you want to clear the textboxes?

Comment: @shaahin - just use `document.forms[0].reset()` to clear all input fields (radio, text, etc) on the form.

Comment: i have to define selector for my textboexes? i want to use it on my reset button. form.reset() is good Idea :)

Comment: you don't need to define anything it will be applied for all `<input type="text"/>` AKA `<asp:TextBox/>` tags on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to clear textboxes inside a panel pnlform. So in your selector you can give a context

```
$("input:text", "#yourpanelid").val('');
```

Comment: this finds all input elements that are of type text inside an element with id yourpanelid.

Answer (score 1):

In a click function I have a link with class reset:

```
$('.reset').click(function(){
    $(':input','#formID')
     .val('')   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`reset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#reset-button) button. It will reset all ( `input` | `select` | `textarea` ) elements within a `form` to their *default* values. The default values are specified by the element like so:

```
<input type="text" name="someName" value="this is a default value" />
```

with radio buttons and check boxes, it will return them to their default checked state.

Edit to add:
Reset buttons work well as a "cancel" button if you have a form where you are making changes to existing data.